# Nvidia driver installation error

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, glibc, header-file

I'm new to the Linux world and I have a problem that is ruining my experience right now. I have installed Linux Mint 19.3 on my Laptop and immediately noticed a lot more battery drainage compared to windows. I installed tlp and it got a lot better, but still worse than windows. I assume it is because of the GPU-drivers aren't installed properly.

So I tried to install the Nvidia-driver manually:
I downloaded the run-file from Nvidia's website, left the GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, stopped the lightdm service, purged everything existing from Nvidia and ran the installation.

After a few steps I get an error message: **You do not appear to have libc header files installed on your system.**

This is where I'm stuck now. How to solve this problem?

Here is an aditional output:

```
    $ dpkg-query -l | grep libc.*dev
    ii  libcolord2:amd64                           1.3.3-2build1                                    amd64        system service to manage device colour profiles -- runtime
    ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                       4.15.0-91.92                                     amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
```

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg-query -l | grep libc.*dev` to your question.

Comment: okay...

$ dpkg-query -l | grep libc.*dev
ii  libcolord2:amd64                           1.3.3-2build1                                    amd64        system service to manage device colour profiles -- runtime
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                       4.15.0-91.92                                     amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the kernel headers but the run file also needs the development header files and binaries. Install them and run the file again:

```
apt-get install libc-dev libc6-dev gcc g++
```

You may already have the last two which are the binaries but I'm including them in case you don't.

Comment: Now the installation worked.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Stan You are welcome. You can accept with the button to the left so that it can help others if they come across the issue.